# Sql: How can i get just last two duplicate rows between more duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table:

```
id  |  title_en  |  value 
--------------------------
1   |     t1     |  1000
2   |     t1     |  2000
3   |     t1     |  3000
4   |     t2     |  4000
5   |     t2     |  5000
6   |     t2     |  6000
```

I want to get the rows they have in their id:

2,3 (for title_en = t1)

and

5,6 (for title_en = t2)

this is my code, but its not working:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY `title_en` HAVING COUNT(`title_en`) > 2
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a coding service

Comment: See item 12 is associated with tag 'Ninja' item 3 is associated with tag 'Pirate' and 'Spaghet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, particuarly in MySQL.  I believe the following does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id >= (select t2.id
               from t t2
               where t2.title_en = t.title_en
               order by t2.id desc
               limit 1 offset 1
              );
```

MySQL is finicky about the use of `limit` in subqueries in the `where` clause.  It is usually okay for a scalar subquery -- one that returns at most one row.

Comment: Thank you, This code will be return last row from each `title_en`. how can i get last two rows from each `title_en` ?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer will be the best when adding `offset` after the `limit` like: limit 1 offset 1.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use GROUP_CONCAT.
And covert comma separated values that GROUP_CONCAT generates into rows with UNION ALL in combination with SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ids, ',', 1), ',', -1) to get a id.
And you need to JOIN that id with your table.

Warning this is kind of hacky to use GROUP_CONCAT this way. You might also want to change group_concat_max_len lenght because it defaults to 1024 bits. 
With

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = val;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Table1.*
FROM ( 

  SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ids, ',', 1), ',', -1)  as id
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM ( 

      SELECT 
        title_en
      , GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC) ids
      FROM 
        Table1
      GROUP BY
        title_en 
      ORDER BY
       title_en ASC
   ) 
     AS
       title1_ids
  ) 
  AS
    row1

  UNION ALL  

  SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ids, ',', 2), ',', -1)  as id
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM ( 

      SELECT 
         title_en
       , GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC) ids
      FROM 
        Table1
      GROUP BY
        title_en 
      ORDER BY
       title_en ASC
     ) 
       AS
       title1_ids
   ) 
    AS
     row2
)
  as rows

INNER JOIN 
 Table1
ON 
 rows.id = Table1.id

ORDER BY
 rows.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
| id | title_en | value |
|----|----------|-------|
|  2 |       t1 |  2000 |
|  3 |       t1 |  3000 |
|  5 |       t2 |  5000 |
|  6 |       t2 |  6000 |
```

demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73377/31

Second solution is to find the second last MAX value off every title_en.
And JOIN that result back with your table.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Table1.*
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     MAX(id) as id
   , title_en
  FROM 
   Table1 
  WHERE
    id NOT IN (
      SELECT
        MAX(id) as id
      FROM 
        Table1
      GROUP BY
        title_en
    )
  GROUP BY
   Table1.title_en
) 
 AS Table1_second_last_max

INNER JOIN 
 Table1
ON 
   Table1.id >= Table1_second_last_max.id
 AND
   Table1.title_en = Table1_second_last_max.title_en
ORDER BY 
  Table1.id
```

**Result**

```
| id | title_en | value |
|----|----------|-------|
|  2 |       t1 |  2000 |
|  3 |       t1 |  3000 |
|  5 |       t2 |  5000 |
|  6 |       t2 |  6000 |
```

demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73377/48

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The number of rows may be millions. And it should also be possible to change the value of each title_en. for example last 3 rows from each title_en or 4 or 5 ...

Answer (score 1):

For the duplicated  rows 
You could use a not in for a subselect  that retrive the oldes id for each title_en

```
  select * from my_table 
  inner join  (
    select id from my_table 
    where (id, title_en ) in not in ( 

      select min(id), title_en
      from my_table
      group by title_en
  ) 
  group by title_en
  having count(*) > 1 ) t on t.id = my_table.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The number of rows may be millions. And it should also be possible to change the value of each title_en. for example last 3 rows from each title_en or 4 or 5 ...

Comment: Yes  .. if you need  a different values for the number of rows  just change the value in having  ... eg : > 2 for 3 rows .. > 3 for 4 rows  and so  .. on